# vim-UltiSnips: expand one snippet in another

Tags: vim, ultisnips

I would like to DRY up my snippets by expanding one snippet from another.

For example some python snippets:

`snippet all
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
endsnippet`

`snippet ia
import $1 as $2
endsnippet`

`snippet future
from __future import print_function`

Is there a way I can call the `ia` snippet and the `future` snippet from within the `all` snippet whilst passing values in for the placeholders?

Comment: If you haven't found anything in the docs, how about opening an issue in the project's tracker? Would certainly make a nice enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

I [submitted a github issue](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/306) about this, and was redirected to [this github issue](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/235).